# 3D model intersect 2D plane

Tags: 3d

I'm searching for a software or DLL or really just a function that would allow me too import a 3D model and a 2D surface. The result of the function would be a 2D surface where both touch.

The 3D model could be in any format.
The 2D surface could be in any format, could even be a 3D model too if required.

[image: 3D Intersect]

But with a surface like this instead of a plane.

[image]

It needs to be FAST and ideally free to use.

I've looked into some Mesh collider in Unity, using small particule to render the surface but it's too slow on computing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found my answer,

https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mesh_boolean.html

The operation I was looking for is named "Mesh Boolean"